# Is this question on topic? Beer from unusual yeast

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I had posted this question and got deleted. Is there anyway I can ask this question and be appropriate?

https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/7333

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had just *asked the question*, explaining what you'd heard (with citation) and asking if that would actually work, that wouldn't have been mod-deleted.  It sounds icky, but that alone wouldn't call for immediate removal.

But you didn't just do that, did you?  No, you included a gratuitous, provocative image to go with your question.  How did doing that improve your question in any way?  Why did you think that would be ok on this site?

Had the question been higher quality it might have been worth fixing the problem with an edit, but I don't blame the moderator who handled it for just deleting.

Comment: I did site the website, but I will delete the picture.

Comment: Yeah, I meant that the question should include the claim and the link should be there for support; nobody should have to click through to see what you're talking about.

Comment: Do you think it would be a biology question? I checked the site isn't as provocative as the picture.